# Is it possible to launch custom app with specific view / scene?

Tags: ios, url-scheme

i'm trying to launch an app from another app in iOS
with some tutorial from [here](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html). So far so good, i could open the app from inside of another app

so far, i've tried scenario like this :
(Let's say app A has trigger to launch app B, app B have views / scenes of menu1, menu2, and menu3)

1. Launch app B, go to deeper view / scene (menu3), minimize, Launch app A, call trigger to Launch app B -> result : B launched look like resumed (menu3 opened)
2. Make sure app B shut down, Launch app A, call trigger to Launch app B -> result : B launched from start of the app (Splash screen -> menu1)

the question is, is it possible to launch with specific scene / view (like directly go to menu2 or menu3)?
i saw at the tutorial i could enter some parameters but i don't understand yet how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass additional information on the custom URL scheme when launching the other app to indicate which screen is desired. The launched app then needs to look at that value in the URL and based on the value, display the desired screen.

Comment: in what class exactly i should write the handler? do you have any good tutorial for passing parameter to another app?

Comment: You do this in the `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` app delegate method.

Comment: thank you, beside

`-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation` method


i'd do something to override scene in `-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *) application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url` method.

with this, i could directly access whatever scene i wanted

Comment: Don't do both. `application:handleOpenURL:` is old. Read the docs for that method.